# Using Gatsby Link with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby Link with TypeScript and I want to pass parameters to linked component from source component.

Gatsby's reference says as following.

> Sometimes you’ll want to pass data from the source page to the linked page. You can do this by passing a state prop to the Link component or on a call to the navigate function. The linked page will have a location prop containing a nested state object structure containing the passed data.

And the sample code with JavaScript is following.

```js
const PhotoFeedItem = ({ id }) => (
  <div>
    {/* (skip the feed item markup for brevity) */}
    <Link
      to={`/photos/${id}`}
      state={{ fromFeed: true }}
    >
      View Photo
    </Link>
  </div>
)

const Photo = ({ location, photoId }) => {
  if (location.state.fromFeed) {
    return <FromFeedPhoto id={photoId} />
  } else {
    return <Photo id={photoId} />
  }
}
```

But with TypeScript, I don't know which type I should use for `props` to get the `location` prop. I tried `GatsbyLinkProps` as props type of linked component but it doesn't contain `location` prop and its `state` prop was `undefined` even though I had passed `state` prop from source component.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location` is an object type of `PageProps` and would need to be passed from your page component to the `Photo` component (assuming `Photo` isn't a page in the coding example).

```
import type { PageProps } from 'gatsby';

interface PhotoProps {
  location: PageProps['location'];
  photoId: string;
}

const Photo = ({ location, photoId }: PhotoProps) ...
```